# why do we need to sync sdkintegration folder into vagrantfile to run sample using fabric-sdk-java?

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I am configuring vagrant environment by following steps mentioned at https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-java

Now, there is step that I have to sync sdkintegration folder as :

```
config.vm.synced_folder "C:/Deepak/projects/btmu/gitsrc/fabric-sdk-java/src/test/fixture/sdkintegration", "/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/sdkintegration"
```

Can you please explain why do we need this step? How things work internally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/synced-folders/ to understand how Vagrant works with synched folders.

But to answer your question, the [Vagrant environment](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/release/devenv/Vagrantfile) this is provided as part of the Hyperledger Fabric repository does not include the fabric-sdk-java code.  In order to mount the fabric-sdk-java code that you cloned on your host system into the Vagrant image, you need to use synched folders (basically it mounts a directory on your host system into the Vagrant image and will keep it in sync).